# Insert marker line in color map

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have created a color map like this:

```
cdict = { 'red': [], 'green': [], 'blue': [] }
def addSect(pos, sect):
   for col in ('red', 'green', 'blue'):
      v = sect.pop(0)
      cdict[col].append((pos, v, v))
colSects = [(0.0, [0,0,1]) , (0.25, [0,1,1]) , (0.25, [0,1,1]) , (0.5, [0,1,0]) , (0.5, [0,1,0]) , (0.75, [1,1,0]) , (0.75, [1,1,0]) , (1.0, [1,0,0])]
for idx in range(len(colSects)):
   sect, col = colSects[idx]
   addSect(sect, col)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('Fire', cdict)
```

This will nicely define a rainbow color map from blue via green to red.

[image]

Now my issue is that I need a black marker somewhere in this color map. The following looks fine on a first glance:

[image]

Which was achieved by inserting the black borders with

```
colSects.insert(1, (0.2, [0,1,1]))
colSects.insert(2, (0.2, [0,0,0]))
colSects.insert(3, (0.22, [0,0,0]))
colSects.insert(4, (0.22, [0,1,1]))
```

But indeed it's not that simple. When placing the marker a bit more to the left

```
colSects.insert(1, (0.1, [0,1,1]))
colSects.insert(2, (0.1, [0,0,0]))
colSects.insert(3, (0.12, [0,0,0]))
colSects.insert(4, (0.12, [0,1,1]))
```

it yields

[image]

You see that the turquoise part is now stretched. But I need the rainbow in the background as above. I would probably need to get the colors at the replacement part and use these in my `insert` statements. But that will involve lots of if-clauses. My question: is there an easy way to set the marker as desired?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want a marker in the colorbar or do you want to have some black region inside the colormap?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It should be a narrow bar so the plot will highlight that area. It's part of the color map.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  It's part of the color map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a new colormap from the original one by inserting black colors into a color list that is created from the original colormap. This would also open the possibility to use a different colormap if needed.

Using the static `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list` method makes everything a lot easier.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

data = np.linspace(0,1,num=50*50).reshape(50,50)

colSects = [(0.0, [0,0,1]) ,(0.25, [0,1,1]) ,
            (0.5, [0,1,0]) , (0.75, [1,1,0]) ,  (1.0, [1,0,0])]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Fire', colSects)
# or use directly
# cmap = plt.cm.jet    

def addblack(cmap, cmin,cmax):
    """ add black between cmin and cmax """
    r = np.arange(int(cmin*255), int(cmax*255), 1)
    colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,256))
    for i in r:
        colors[i] = (0,0,0,1)
    return matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('newcmap', colors)

cmap = addblack(cmap, 0.1,0.12)
plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I thought to have compared the jet map with mine and had the impression that it was different. Will look again!

Comment: The jet map is much darker and has less green. But thanks anyway for your great solution!